# html 100% height with 200px bottom margin?

Tags: html, css, height, margin

please can some brilliant person help me with this page layout or tell me if it is possible?

Trying to embed some flash content which resizes with the browser but has a 400px margin on the left and a 200px margin at the bottom. Have managed to get the margin on the left but cannot get the bottom margin to stay within the browser.

My div looks like this:

```
<div style="height:100%;margin-left:400px;">
    <div id="flashcontent"></div>
</div>
```

The swf is embedded with swfobject into the flashcontent div dynamically, Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: try to float div and see what happens

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, tried adding float to the div but now the flash content is tiny (about 100px X 100px) and no margin on the bottom. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If you can afford not to support IE6, I guess you could work with `position: fixed`.

It's not very elegant but from the sound of it (you don't seem to have any other layout considerations to take care of on this page), it might do.

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 400px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 200px;">
    <div id="flashcontent"></div>
</div>
```

I can't test this right now, but the `flashcontent` div should now be able to resize according to the outlying div.

Comment: Wow, thats brilliant this has been driving me mad, do you know of any workaround for IE6? Would be willing to get something on your wishlist. Many thanks either way

Comment: @mike mmm, you could try `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`. That should work too, as long as your `html` and `body` elements are 100% tall, and the document doesn't stretch beyond the bottom border (i.e. is exactly 100% tall). Give feedback if it doesn't work out. Getting me something from my wish list is entirely voluntary, but always welcome! :)

Comment: Will test for IE6, but can't thank you enough, will keep you posted. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- This comment makes IE render in quirks mode.. We want IE in quirks mode -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
<style type="text/css">
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
.flash-container {
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f00;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:0 0 200px 400px;
}
.flash {
    background-color: #fff;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flash-container">
    <div class="flash">
        ...Replace this Div with Flash
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pekkas answer is pretty good, I didn't consider the option of setting all edges. But I also made this table proposal, which should work in just about all browsers since the dawn of time.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:100%;"> 
<body style="padding:0;margin:0;height:100%;">
<table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td style="width:400px;">1</td>
    <td style="background-color:red;">2</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:200px;">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Svend, thanks for the response but the main content is an embedded swf, tried your code but in IE8 the bottom goes outside the browser and in Chrome the bottom is fine but it squashes the swf. Any ideas? Mike

Comment: Ugh! Using tables for layout is like eating at McDonalds every day: It does work in the short, but you end up dying coated in fat.

Comment: @xPheRe Knowing what it is, is still a powerful tool, you can fall back on, if CSS doesn't provide a good solution for you, or requires very bleeding edge stuff, that maybe isn't available. Nothing wrong with knowing what McDonalds is, and eating a burger there once a year maybe ;)